# how to do customized stencil test in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, stencil-buffer

In my project, I used 'discard' call to perform customized stencil test, which tries to  draw things only on a specified area defined by a stencil texture. Here is the code from fragment shader:

```
//get the stencil value from a texture
float value=texture2D( stencilTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy/1024.0).x;
//check if value equals the desired value, if not draw nothing
if(abs(value-desiredValue)>0.1)
{
    discard;
}
```

This code works, but suffers from a performance problem because of the 'discard' call. Is there an alternative way to do this through GPU Shaders? Tell me how.

Comment: why cannot you use default stencil test (not in shaders)? you will get the same result.

Comment: "*alliterative*" I think you meant "alternative". Also, it's not clear why you need to use a *stencil* texture to do this. Or why it is you think that the `discard` call is a performance problem (or if it is a performance problem, that the problem is somehow worse than the texture access itself).

Comment: @NicolBolas: sorry for my misspelling, in my experiment I found that discard call is a performance problem, which is also reported by [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl)

Comment: @fen: thanks for your reply. I want to use stencil test in shaders because I want to implement drawing my scene on different predefined areas in a single render pass.

Comment: @Sunf71: Then it's not really a "stencil test"; it's just discarding a fragment based on a value fetched from a texture access. Stenciling is specifically about using values written by one rendered object (visible or not) to prevent writes to those rendered locations.

Comment: @Sunf71: "*in my experiment I found that discard call is a performance problem*" On what hardware? And are you sure you tested it correctly? Are you sure you're not just measuring the time it takes to access the "stencil" texture? Because if you remove the `discard`, and you don't use the fetched value anywhere, then most compilers will completely optimize out the texture access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you access a texture, you must suffer the performance penalties associated with accessing a texture. In the same way, if you want to stop a fragment from being rendered, you must suffer the performance penalties associated with stopping fragments from being rendered.

This will be true regardless of *how* you stop that fragment. Whether it's a true stencil test, your shader-based `discard`, or alpha testing, all of these will encounter the same general performance issues (for hardware where `discard` leads to any significant performance problems, which is mainly mobile hardware). The only exception is the depth test, and that's because of [why certain hardware has problems with `discard`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8509158/734069).

For platforms where `discard` has a substantial impact in performance, the rendering algorithm works most optimally if the hardware can assume that the depth is the final arbiter of whether a fragment will be rendered (and thus, the fragment with the highest/lowest depth always wins). Therefore, any method of culling the fragment other than the depth test will interfere with this optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Very reasonalble answer!