# ios - How to benchmark a shader

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How does one benchmark relatively simple shader? I need to determine such things like what to do: discard in the beginning or multiply by 0 in the end of shader.

What I'm struggling with is general approach to benchmark glsl shaders and also, how to benchmark particular shader, because it has no effect on general performance (like fps etc) but I need to determine what is the difference.

Comment: as a general rule, discard is not that effective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl

Comment: thats is just an example. I need general approach because it is one of many many things i want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES debugger in Xcode might give you a good insight about which shader takes how much time and what parts of shader are consuming more time than other parts.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/debugging_opengl_es_frame.html