# webgl: fastest approach to drawing many circles

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm currently drawing thousands of circles, instancing a [circle geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry) (many triangles).

[image]

alternatively, I could simply instance a quad (2 triangles), but cut out a circle in the fragment shader, using a distance function and `discard`.

[image]

which approach would be faster? -- is drawing many triangles more expensive than the calculations done in the fragment shader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way might depend on the GPU and lots of other factors like how you're drawing the circles, 2D, 3D, are you blending them, are you using the z-buffer, etc... but in general, less triangles is faster than more, and less pixels is faster than more. So...., all we can really do is try.

First let's just draw textured quads with no blending. First off I always seem to get inconsistent perf from WebGL but in my tests on my GPU I get 20k-30k quads at 60fps in this 300x150 canvas using instancing

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  
  const vs = `
  attribute float id;
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  
  uniform float time;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main() {
    float o = id + time;
    gl_Position = position + vec4(
        vec2(
             fract(o * 0.1373),
             fract(o * 0.5127)) * 2.0 - 1.0,
        0, 0);
        
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_color = vec4(fract(vec3(id) * vec3(0.127, 0.373, 0.513)), 1);
  }`;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord) * v_color;
  }
  `; 
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const maxCount = 250000;
  const ids = new Float32Array(maxCount);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    ids[i] = i;
  }
  const x = 16 / 300 * 2;
  const y = 16 / 150 * 2;
  
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
       -x, -y,
        x, -y,
       -x,  y,
       -x,  y,
        x, -y,
        x,  y,
        ],
    },
    texcoord: [
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 0,    
    ],
    id: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: ids,
      divisor: 1,
    }
  });
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  {
    const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = 32;
    ctx.canvas.height = 32;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(16, 16, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, { src: ctx.canvas });
  }
  
  const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
  const countElem = document.querySelector('#count');
  
  let count;  
  function getCount() {
    count = Math.min(maxCount, parseInt(countElem.value));
  }
  
  countElem.addEventListener('input', getCount);
  getCount();
  
  const maxHistory = 60;
  const fpsHistory = new Array(maxHistory).fill(0);
  let historyNdx = 0;
  let historyTotal = 0;
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    
    historyTotal += deltaTime - fpsHistory[historyNdx];
    fpsHistory[historyNdx] = deltaTime;
    historyNdx = (historyNdx + 1) % maxHistory;
    
    fpsElem.textContent = (1000 / (historyTotal / maxHistory)).toFixed(1);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {time: now * 0.001});
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, count);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
<div>count: <input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="1000000" value="25000"></div>
```

And I get the same perf at 60fps using repeated to geometry instead of instancing. That's surprising to me because 7-8yrs ago when I tested repeated geometry was 20-30% faster. Whether that's because of having a better GPU now or a better driver or what I have no idea.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  
  const vs = `
  attribute float id;
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  
  uniform float time;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main() {
    float o = id + time;
    gl_Position = position + vec4(
        vec2(
             fract(o * 0.1373),
             fract(o * 0.5127)) * 2.0 - 1.0,
        0, 0);
        
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_color = vec4(fract(vec3(id) * vec3(0.127, 0.373, 0.513)), 1);
  }`;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord) * v_color;
  }
  `; 
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const maxCount = 250000;
  const x = 16 / 300 * 2;
  const y = 16 / 150 * 2;
  
  const quadPositions = [
     -x, -y,
      x, -y,
     -x,  y,
     -x,  y,
      x, -y,
      x,  y,
  ];
  const quadTexcoords = [
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
      0, 0,
      0, 0,
      1, 1,
      1, 0,    
  ];
  const positions = new Float32Array(maxCount * 2 * 6);
  const texcoords = new Float32Array(maxCount * 2 * 6);
  for (let i = 0; i < maxCount; ++i) {
    const off = i * 2 * 6;
    positions.set(quadPositions, off);
    texcoords.set(quadTexcoords, off);
  }
  const ids = new Float32Array(maxCount * 6);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    ids[i] = i / 6 | 0;
  }
      
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: positions,
    },
    texcoord: texcoords,
    id: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: ids,
    }
  });
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  {
    const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = 32;
    ctx.canvas.height = 32;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(16, 16, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, { src: ctx.canvas });
  }
  
  const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
  const countElem = document.querySelector('#count');
  
  let count;  
  function getCount() {
    count = Math.min(maxCount, parseInt(countElem.value));
  }
  
  countElem.addEventListener('input', getCount);
  getCount();
  
  const maxHistory = 60;
  const fpsHistory = new Array(maxHistory).fill(0);
  let historyNdx = 0;
  let historyTotal = 0;
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    
    historyTotal += deltaTime - fpsHistory[historyNdx];
    fpsHistory[historyNdx] = deltaTime;
    historyNdx = (historyNdx + 1) % maxHistory;
    
    fpsElem.textContent = (1000 / (historyTotal / maxHistory)).toFixed(1);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {time: now * 0.001});
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * count);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
<div>count: <input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="1000000" value="25000"></div>
```

Next thing would be textures or computing a circle in the fragment shader.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  
  const vs = `
  attribute float id;
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  
  uniform float time;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main() {
    float o = id + time;
    gl_Position = position + vec4(
        vec2(
             fract(o * 0.1373),
             fract(o * 0.5127)) * 2.0 - 1.0,
        0, 0);
        
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_color = vec4(fract(vec3(id) * vec3(0.127, 0.373, 0.513)), 1);
  }`;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = mix(
       v_color, 
       vec4(0), 
       step(1.0, length(v_texcoord.xy * 2. - 1.)));
  }
  `; 
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const maxCount = 250000;
  const ids = new Float32Array(maxCount);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    ids[i] = i;
  }
  const x = 16 / 300 * 2;
  const y = 16 / 150 * 2;
  
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
       -x, -y,
        x, -y,
       -x,  y,
       -x,  y,
        x, -y,
        x,  y,
        ],
    },
    texcoord: [
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 0,    
    ],
    id: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: ids,
      divisor: 1,
    }
  });
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
  const countElem = document.querySelector('#count');
  
  let count;  
  function getCount() {
    count = Math.min(maxCount, parseInt(countElem.value));
  }
  
  countElem.addEventListener('input', getCount);
  getCount();
  
  const maxHistory = 60;
  const fpsHistory = new Array(maxHistory).fill(0);
  let historyNdx = 0;
  let historyTotal = 0;
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    
    historyTotal += deltaTime - fpsHistory[historyNdx];
    fpsHistory[historyNdx] = deltaTime;
    historyNdx = (historyNdx + 1) % maxHistory;
    
    fpsElem.textContent = (1000 / (historyTotal / maxHistory)).toFixed(1);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {time: now * 0.001});
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, count);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
<div>count: <input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="1000000" value="25000"></div>
```

I get no measureable difference. Trying your circle function

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  
  const vs = `
  attribute float id;
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  
  uniform float time;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main() {
    float o = id + time;
    gl_Position = position + vec4(
        vec2(
             fract(o * 0.1373),
             fract(o * 0.5127)) * 2.0 - 1.0,
        0, 0);
        
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_color = vec4(fract(vec3(id) * vec3(0.127, 0.373, 0.513)), 1);
  }`;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  float circle(in vec2 st, in float radius) {
    vec2 dist = st - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - smoothstep(
       radius - (radius * 0.01),
       radius +(radius * 0.01),
       dot(dist, dist) * 4.0);
  }
  
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = mix(
       vec4(0), 
       v_color, 
       circle(v_texcoord, 1.0));
  }
  `; 
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const maxCount = 250000;
  const ids = new Float32Array(maxCount);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    ids[i] = i;
  }
  const x = 16 / 300 * 2;
  const y = 16 / 150 * 2;
  
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
       -x, -y,
        x, -y,
       -x,  y,
       -x,  y,
        x, -y,
        x,  y,
        ],
    },
    texcoord: [
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 0,    
    ],
    id: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: ids,
      divisor: 1,
    }
  });
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
  const countElem = document.querySelector('#count');
  
  let count;  
  function getCount() {
    count = Math.min(maxCount, parseInt(countElem.value));
  }
  
  countElem.addEventListener('input', getCount);
  getCount();
  
  const maxHistory = 60;
  const fpsHistory = new Array(maxHistory).fill(0);
  let historyNdx = 0;
  let historyTotal = 0;
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    
    historyTotal += deltaTime - fpsHistory[historyNdx];
    fpsHistory[historyNdx] = deltaTime;
    historyNdx = (historyNdx + 1) % maxHistory;
    
    fpsElem.textContent = (1000 / (historyTotal / maxHistory)).toFixed(1);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {time: now * 0.001});
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, count);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
<div>count: <input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="1000000" value="25000"></div>
```

I again get no measurable difference. Note: like I said above I get wildly inconsistent results in WebGL. When I ran the first test I got 28k at 60fps. When I ran the second I got 23k. I was surprised since I expected the 2nd to be faster so I ran the first again and only got 23k. The last one I got 29k and was again surprise but then I went back and did the previous and got 29k. Basically that means testing timing in WebGL is nearly impossible. There are so many moving parts given everything is multi-process that getting constant results seems impossible.

Could try discard

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  
  const vs = `
  attribute float id;
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  
  uniform float time;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main() {
    float o = id + time;
    gl_Position = position + vec4(
        vec2(
             fract(o * 0.1373),
             fract(o * 0.5127)) * 2.0 - 1.0,
        0, 0);
        
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_color = vec4(fract(vec3(id) * vec3(0.127, 0.373, 0.513)), 1);
  }`;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  float circle(in vec2 st, in float radius) {
    vec2 dist = st - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - smoothstep(
       radius - (radius * 0.01),
       radius +(radius * 0.01),
       dot(dist, dist) * 4.0);
  }
  
  void main() {
    if (circle(v_texcoord, 1.0) < 0.5) {
      discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
  }
  `; 
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const maxCount = 250000;
  const ids = new Float32Array(maxCount);
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    ids[i] = i;
  }
  const x = 16 / 300 * 2;
  const y = 16 / 150 * 2;
  
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
       -x, -y,
        x, -y,
       -x,  y,
       -x,  y,
        x, -y,
        x,  y,
        ],
    },
    texcoord: [
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 0,    
    ],
    id: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: ids,
      divisor: 1,
    }
  });
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  const fpsElem = document.querySelector('#fps');
  const countElem = document.querySelector('#count');
  
  let count;  
  function getCount() {
    count = Math.min(maxCount, parseInt(countElem.value));
  }
  
  countElem.addEventListener('input', getCount);
  getCount();
  
  const maxHistory = 60;
  const fpsHistory = new Array(maxHistory).fill(0);
  let historyNdx = 0;
  let historyTotal = 0;
  
  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    
    historyTotal += deltaTime - fpsHistory[historyNdx];
    fpsHistory[historyNdx] = deltaTime;
    historyNdx = (historyNdx + 1) % maxHistory;
    
    fpsElem.textContent = (1000 / (historyTotal / maxHistory)).toFixed(1);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {time: now * 0.001});
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, count);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
<div>count: <input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="1000000" value="25000"></div>
```

Given the inconsistent timing I can't be sure but my impression is discard is slower. IIRC discard is slow because without discard the GPU knows even before it executes the fragment shader that it's going to update the z-buffer where as with discard it doesn't know until after the shader executes and that that difference means certain things can't be optimized as well.

I'm going to stop there because there's just too many combinations of things to try.

We could try blending on. Blending is also generally slower though since it has to blend (read the background) but is it slower than discard? I don't know.

Do you have the depth test on? If so then draw order will be important.

Yet another thing to test is using non-quads like hexgons or octogons as that would run less pixels through the fragment shader. I suspect you might need to make the circles bigger to see that but if we have a 100x100 pixel quad that's 10k pixels. If we have perfect circle geometry that's about pi*r^2 or ~7853 or 21% less pixels. A Hexagon would be ~8740 pixels or 11% less. An octogon somewhere in between. Drawing 11% to 21% less pixels is usually a win but of course course for hexagon you'd be drawing 3x more triangles, for an octogon 4x more. You'd basically have to test all these cases.

That points out another issue in that I believe you'd get different relative results with larger circles on a larger canvas since there'd be more pixels per circle so for any given number of circles drawn more % of time would be spent drawing pixels and less calculating vertices and/or less time restarting the GPU to draw the next circle.

### Update

Testing on Chrome vs Firefox I got 60k-66k in all cases in Chrome on the same machine. No idea why the difference is so vast given that WebGL itself is doing almost nothing. All 4 tests only have a single draw call per frame. But whatever, at least as of 2019-10 Chrome as more than twice as fast for this particular case than Firefox

One idea is I have a dual GPU laptop. When you create the context you can tell WebGL what you're targeting by passing in the `powerPreference` context creation attribute as in in

```
const gl = document.createContext('webgl', {
  powerPreference: 'high-performance',
});
```

The options are 'default', 'low-power', 'high-performance'. 'default' means "let the browser decide" but ultimately all of them mean "let the browser decide". In any case setting that above didn't change anything in firefox for me.

Comment: re: discard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl

Comment: interesting... -- thank you for putting all the effort into testing all of this!
I thought perhaps there is a definitive answer (I don't really know much about the inner workings of 3d graphics), but if it's a case of "it depends on too many things, so it's hard to actually know", I'll probably stop trying to optimize here. I am already (un)loading the data the circles represent as needed, so trying to keep the total number of circles being displayed as low as possible is enough, I suppose.