# glsl conditionally assigning out_color

Tags: glsl, vulkan, shaderc

I'm trying to achieve blending by using a shader to *conditionally* assign the fragment color.

Full shader code...

```
#version 450
#pragma shader_stage(fragment)

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texture_sampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 tex_coord;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 _rgba;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

void main() {
    vec4 oc = textureLod(texture_sampler, tex_coord, 0);

    if (oc.r > _rgba.r)
        oc.r = _rgba.r;
    
    if (oc.g > _rgba.g)
        oc.g = _rgba.g;
    
    if (oc.b > _rgba.b)
        oc.b = _rgba.b;

    if (oc.a > _rgba.a)
        oc.a = _rgba.a;

    float threshhold = .5;

    if (oc.a > threshhold)
        out_color = oc;
}
```

(this flickers at run time btw...)

[image: flickering garbage]

changing the last bit of code to...

```
    float threshhold = .5;

    //if (oc.a > threshhold)
        out_color = oc;
```

does this...

[image: rendered clean but with black background]

If I remove the assignment completely, the text just dissappears. It seems that having the assignment there makes the driver expect it to always be assigned. Does anyone know why this is happening? Why can't I *conditionally* leave the pixel unmodified? Is there something I have to change in my Vulkan code for the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration in a shader

`layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;`

is basically telling the pipeline that whatever value `out_color` ends up with at the end of execution is what should go in the framebuffer.  You're not allowed to just not assign a value.  If you fail to write the value it's the same as having an uninitialized variable in C.  The contents will be random based on whatever happened to be in that memory address at the start of execution.

From the [GL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)) (but still applicable to GLSL shaders for Vulkan)

> The shader must set all output variables at some point in its execution

The only two exceptions this.  The first is if the output variable isn't being read by subsequent stages.  In this case, there are no subsequent stages, and the variable is the output going to the framebuffer, so that's not applicable.

The second is in fragment shaders where you use the `discard` keyword.  You're not using `discard` in your shader, but most likely that would fix your problem.  Try changing your code to

```
    if (oc.a > threshhold)
        out_color = oc;
    else
        discard;
```

However, bear in mind that `discard` as a keyword can impact performance of the entire pipeline because it can no longer assume that every evaluation of the shader will produce output.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl)

Comment: `discard` seems to be the magic word I was looking for, thanks! Would it be faster or more correct to do another render pass to avoid using it though?

Comment: Like the linked question says... the discard penalty is hardware dependent.  If you're targeting desktop rendering I doubt I'd bother worrying about it until you have some evidence it's a bottleneck.  If you're targeting mobile I'd only be slightly more concerned.  Adding an additional renderpass is a high maintenance burden if you haven't identified it as a performance problem.  Additionally, you could just just set out_color.a to 0 if it's below the threshold and never discard.

Comment: conditionally setting `out_color.a = 0` instead of discard has the same behaviour as before. setting `out_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)` will render black instead of transparent. any idea why?

Comment: Yeah, the `out_color.a = 0` actually would depend on what your blend settings are, and would really only work if you are blending with a pre-existing image in a pretty specific way that's commonly used for transparency passes.  Should have mentioned.  If this is your primary pass (and you're not preserving the previous frame's buffer) then that likely won't work.  If `out_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)` renders black you likely don't have any blend mode turned on at all and the alpha channel is being ignored in terms of the framebuffer output.